# Unable to run VMWare workstation after installation on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: vmware, 20.10, vmware-workstation

After successfully installed VMWare workstation 15.5.5 in Ubuntu 20.10, I am unable to run vmware workstation. Please help,Details are as follows:

```
sudo ./VMware-Workstation-Full-15.5.5-16285975.x86_64.bundle
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
Installing VMware Workstation 15.5.5
Configuring...
[######################################################################] 100%
Installation was successful.

rasool@finding:~/Downloads$ sudo vmware
/usr/bin/vmware: line 105: 20655 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) "$BINDIR"/vmware- 
modconfig --appname="VMware Workstation" --icon="vmware-workstation"

rasool@finding:~/Downloads$ vmware
/usr/bin/vmware: line 105: 20680 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) "$BINDIR"/vmware- 
modconfig --appname="VMware Workstation" --icon="vmware-workstation"
```